# How to read images from excel sheet using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, excel

I am using **excel-paser** to read content of excel sheet. I just get empty value if there some images in excel sheet. But i need to fetch both **images and content simultaneously**. After spending long time in finding a better way to fix my issue i came to know that images will be **zipped in a xml file for excel sheet** from where i can get image contents. But i dont see any practical explanation theory in order that i can complete my stuff.

Please i f anybody can help me to fix this stuff guide me. **Thanks in Advance!!**

Answer (score 0):

1. After unpack xlsx file you can  found all images in `/xl/media`
   folder.
2. Search in xmls by name of image =>
       `xl\drawings\_rels\drawing1.xml.rels` as result.
3. In this file you can found ref e.g. `<Relationship Id="rId1"...`. `rId1` is image reference in other xml-files.

So, you need 2 modules to zip and to xml-parsing.